# Htaccess redirect rule adds an unwanted variable

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I'm trying to redirect logged-in users that land on a page to another page, but the redirect keeps adding the logged-in user's name to the path / URL.

Say I'm logged in as Mario.  The redirect includes that username into the redirected path, throwing up a 404 error.

Below is the content of the .htaccess file (without the redirect):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js.gz|js.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css.gz|css.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/e500\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/captcha\.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (/|\.php|\.htm|\.feed|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

This is my redirect:

```
Redirect /photo/useralbums /my-profile
```

The result is that the user ends up at: `/my-profile/Mario`

Comment: How are you determining that a user is "logged in"?

Comment: Because when I test it, the logged-in user's name gets included in the path. Your solution below did the trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect /photo/useralbums /my-profile
> ```
>
> The result is that the user ends up at: `/my-profile/Mario`

This will happen if the request is for `/photo/useralbums/Mario` since the mod_alias  `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL.

If you need to redirect all URLs of the form `/photo/useralbums/<username>` to `/my-profile` then you will either need to use the mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive, which matches using a regex and is not prefix-matching, or use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive. Since you are already using mod_rewrite for an internal rewrite you should use the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive for the redirect as well in order to avoid potential future conflicts. (Different Apache modules run independently and at different times during the request. mod_rewrite always runs before mod_alias despite the apparent order of directives in your `.htaccess` file.)

Redirects should generally go *before* internal rewrites, so try the following instead *before* your existing mod_rewrite directives:

```
RewriteRule ^photo/useralbums(/[\w-]*)?$ /my-profile [R,L]
```

Note there is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The above will redirect `/photo/useralbums`, `/photo/useralbums/` or `/photo/useralbums/<username>` (but not `/photo/useralbums/<username>/something`) to `/my-profile`. Where `<username>` can consist of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` or `-`.

However, this doesn't determine whether the user is "logged in" or not, as suggested in your question, since the redirect is unconditional.